# C# Sending user input from one form to another without the second form opening

Tags: c#, list, winforms, input

I'm currently trying to send customer names from one listbox in form1 to another listbox in a separate form (form2). I want to do this by when the user clicks the add button the customer name it will automatically send it to the other form without the second form opening. Is this possible?

Also currently if I exit from form1 and go back into it without closing the program all the input in the listbox is lost, is it possible to save the input in there some how?

Form 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Creates a controller object
    Controller control = new Controller();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DisplayCustomers();

     //   FormAccounts formA = new FormAccounts(listBoxCustomer);
    }

    // Add Customer
    // Completed
    private void buttonAddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.firstName = textBox1.Text;
        control.Add(c);
        // control.list.Add(c);
        listBoxCustomer.Items.Add(c.firstName);
       
    }


    // Displays Customers to list box
    public void DisplayCustomers()
    {
        listBoxCustomer.Items.Clear();
        foreach(Customer c in control.list)
        {
            listBoxCustomer.Items.Add(c.FirstName);
        }

    }
 

 }
}
```

Form 2:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
  { 

    Controller control = new Controller();
   
    public FormAccounts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DisplayCustomers();
    }

 // Displays Customers to list box
    public void DisplayCustomers()
    {
        listBoxCustomerName.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Customer c in control.list)
        {
            listBoxCustomerName.Items.Add(c.FirstName);
        }

    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
class Controller
 {

    public List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();

    // Method to create customer object
    public void CreateCustomer(string firstName)
    {
        list.Add(new Customer(firstName));
    }

    // Add Customer
    public void Add(Customer c)
    {
        list.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Customer class:

```
class Customer
 {

    private List<Account> customerAccounts;

    private static int nextID = 1;
    public int customerId;
    public string firstName;

    public int CustomerId { get => customerId; set => customerId = value; }
    public string FirstName { get => firstName; set => firstName = value; }

    public Customer()
    {
        CustomerId = nextID;
        nextID++;
    }

    public Customer(string newFirstName) : this()
    {
        FirstName = newFirstName;

    }
```

Comment: Where/when is form2 eventually getting open and displayed to the user? It seems pointless to add info to form2 considering form2 may never be displayed. Just before form2 is eventually displayed, get the values from the list box in form1 and pass those values into form2’s constructor. However, as commented, this depends on “when/where” is form2 displayed to the user?

Comment: You can use simple DataBinding. I.e., you can bind your ListBoxes to the list exposed by your (fake :) `Controller`. This implies that `Customer` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. After that, each time you show Form2 (in case you show it) and bind the customers' list to a Control, as your ListBox or anything else, it's updated to the current content of the List of Customers. Nothing else required. As the `DisplayCustomers()` method, which appears not that useful anyway, as currently defined.